# How to override TSDoc/JSDoc from props that are common to multiple prop type definitions?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, jsdoc, tsdoc

I'm building a React component (`EmailHeader`) with Typescript and I'm trying to define its props types. It receives some props directly from the parent (`EmailEditor`), and on the Props type declaration I'm merging its own props with the ones it inherits, to keep them sync, like so:

```js
export type EmailHeaderProps = Pick<EmailEditorProps, 'availableSenders'> &
    Pick<EmailEditorProps['email'], 'sender' | 'recipients' | 'subject'> & {
        // Own props are defined here
    };
```

However, I'd like to override its **TSDoc/JSDoc** and add more specific information that the props from the parent don't need.

Is there any way that I can do this, while keeping the props in sync? Or do I have to abandon this idea and explicitly declare each property again with the custom TSDoc/JSDoc?